# Passing date string to a function in an ibatis query

Tags: ibatis

I am passing a date string to an ibatis query which is used for comparison. However, I am getting an error

```
SELECT PATIENT_SUFFIX_NM,
       INTRPT_CLM_TXT,
       DAYS(DATE(#{batch_dt_ud})) - DAYS(INTRPT_CLM_ENTR_TS) AGE_OF_CLAIM
FROM INTERRUPTED_CLAIM
WHERE KEYER_ID=#{keyer_id}
```

THe error is

> "A STATEMENT STRING TO BE PREPARED CONTAINS AN INVALID USE OF PARAMETER MARKERS"

and it is complaining about the date function usage of `DAYS(DATE(#{batch_dt_ud}))`.
Can i not pass an ibatis string parameter to the date function ?.

Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

you can try by defining a parameterMap.

```
<parameterMap id="ParameterMapName"  type="ClassTypeOfHowYouPassParameters">
    <parameter property="keyer_id" mode="IN"/>
    <parameter property="batch_dt_ud" jdbcType="DATE" mode="IN"/>
</parameterMap>
```

Your query will be something like:

```
<select id="QueryNameForCalling" parameterMap="ParameterMapName" resultType="string">
       SELECT PATIENT_SUFFIX_NM,
       INTRPT_CLM_TXT,
       DAYS(DATE(#{batch_dt_ud})) - DAYS(INTRPT_CLM_ENTR_TS) AGE_OF_CLAIM
       FROM INTERRUPTED_CLAIM
       WHERE KEYER_ID=#{keyer_id}
</select>
```

I am making an assumption that you return a string `resultType="string"`